# Why can't I get my script tag src's to work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been coding up a localhost, and I made the localhost by using of course a JavaScript file to do so, and I then made it reference an HTML file. However, I noticed that when I am using localhost to serve up the HTML file I get this error:

```
"GET http://localhost:3333/filetesting.js"
```

The `filetesting.js` is that js file, there are also other things I'm referencing too, like websites. I'm referencing it by using script tag `src`.

I looked at the network on developer tools of it and it says it's a 404 error not found. I'm trying to figure out how to reference my script tag src's without having `localhost:3333` go before it.

When I run the HTML file without using the localhost, it works just fine when it comes to the script tag src's. If you do not entirely understand what I'm asking for, just ask.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How **exactly** are you referencing this script?
 In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Did you configure and run a web server on your computer? And put your JS file in the directory served by this web server?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your script will always reside in the **root** level of your website, you can simply target it with the **[root-relative prefix](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php?ref)** `/`:

```
<script src="/filetesting.js"></script>
```

This will load your script from the root, regardless of the site the file is hosted on. For example, on `http://localhost:3333/` it will load the file from `http://localhost:3333/filetesting.js`, and from `http://localhost:3333/folder/`, it will attempt to load the file from the **same** location.

If you move your files over to a proper website, it will still work the same way: `www.example.com` will look for the file at `www.example.com/filetesting.js`, and `www.example.com/folder/` will look for the same file at `www.example.com/filetesting.js`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! This helped!

Comment: Glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)